# Unable to send SMS using SmsManager in Android 13

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I am trying to develop an app that sends SMS. However, the SMS does not get accepted by the network. But if I manually send it, it works.

I have given the following permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

And my function to send SMS is:

```
private void sendSms(String body, String ph) {
    SmsManager smsManager =  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(SmsManager.class).createForSubscriptionId(0);
    ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(body);
    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(ph, null, parts, null, null);
}
```

I have also tried `createForSubscriptionId(1)` and still the same result.

The outgoing SMS is kept in the conversation thread with an error: `Not sent, tap to try again`. When I tap, it says `error 2`.

It did send 3 SMS initially and then never sent them again. Can anybody help?

Comment: Sounds like the device itself is having problems sending messages.  Can you send a text to the same number via the Messages app?  Also, what is ph-  let's make sure the number is properly formatted.

Comment: @GabeSechan, as I mentioned, sending manually works fine. Phone number was given with international dialing code.

Comment: If you don't want to give the actual number (understandable), put it with letters for the number part.  We need to make sure you're formatting it correctly.

Comment: @GabeSechan, the phone number was given like "+91xxxxxxxxxx" (without quotes)

Comment: @GabeSechan, I did also try `SmsManager.getDefault()`, although it was deprecated, it also behaved the same.

Comment: I'm also having the exact same problem on Android 13. Has anyone managed to solve it?

Comment: @MatteoPasini it seemed like an android restriction